# jQuery ajaxComplete Event: Detect whether response has been taken from cache

Tags: jquery

I have a strange issue in that I'm listening for HTTP headers returned by the server registering myself on the `ajaxComplete` event (using jQuery). Now on Chrome I noticed that the `ajaxComplete` also gets called when Chrome takes the actual content from cache, thus also providing me potentially old header information (really weird).

**My question:** is there a way to detect whether a given response has been taken from cache??

(Note: I know about the different cache settings you can add to an ajax call, but as mentioned I'm just registering myself on the `ajaxComplete` with no control on the actual executed ajax call)